# Reason behind allowing multiple null values for unique constraints in innodb

Tags: database-design, innodb

My question is not how to prevent multiple null values in unique constraints. I already know how to solve that, but if I search I get the how part of the answer, not the why part!

What I'm wondering about is to why this behavior is allowed. What logic is behind this and what is this idea called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `NULL` is literally "unknown" and not even equal to another `NULL`. It is not a distinct value itself. So you can have multiple NULLs in a `UNIQUE` index because `NULL != NULL`.

Comment: I see, something like a placeholder to add distinct values in the future